# Restrict SSH access to git usage only

Tags: ssh, git, key-authentication, account-restrictions

Using:

- [`ssh-keygen -O force-command="/bin/restricted-command"`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/ssh-keygen.1), or
- [`command="/bin/restricted-command"`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man8/sshd.8) at the beginning of an `authorized_keys` line

one can force a key-based SSH connection to execute the given command and no other.

Is it possible through this mechanism (or another) to **give someone a limited SSH access to a given git repository**, allowing that person to `git clone user@server:myrepo.git`, `push` or `pull`, but nothing else?

<sub>Security note: when restricting access with `authorized_keys`, you should also use the options: `no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-user-rc`</sub>

Comment: Look at `gitolite` which manages these details for you.

Comment: Perhaps you want to use chroot for this ssh user.

Comment: install git-shell (git-sh on Debian) and change the shell for the user to git-shell.

Comment: @Dārayavahuštdi is this a guaranteed secure shell? Meaning that this user cannot escape from it or do anything else on the system?